# How does Openshift handle sessions by default in auto-scaling applications?

Tags: session, tomcat, wicket, openshift, autoscaling

Using Tomcat7 on OpenShift Online (free plan), I created a simple Java web application using Apache Wicket as front-end framework. I was wondering how OpenShift deals by default with sessions when an additional gear is started to support a traffic peak.

Are requests within the same session always handled by the same gear, or is it possible that two subsequent requests are handled by different gears?

If requests are handled by different gears, will the session be available on both?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior that OpenShift uses for HA-Proxy (the load balancer) is session affinity - so each connection should stay on the gear it started on. If it doesn't do that behavior then there is a bug. Please let us know if you see that.

If you want sessions to survive if there is a failure on one of your application servers then you would need to use a server technology that clusters - like JBoss EAP. I am not sure if tomcat 7 on OpenShift is configured for clustering by default.